# how to combine animations of different objects into 1 animation

Tags: animation, dopesheet, timeline

I made a 0.50 second animation for firing, but it splits into different animations, and when i want to save it in action editor in dope sheet, i see lots of names.
i think it's because I'm animating different objects all together. how can i combine them all into 1 animation name. so it becomes 1 animation "name" and it moves all the parts i want to move ?
or if it's not possible to combine them, how can i start a new animation, but put all the moving parts into 1 timeline?

[image]

it's been three days that I'm using blender, I'm a newbie. I'm just trying to make some objects to use in unity.

Thanks for reading my question

Comment: I'm mentioning this as you've only been a Blenderite for 3 days + 4...  Whilst I'm not aware of a "Package" wrap, saving it all as one, you can however isolate the gun's animations in the Dopesheet for keyframe manipulation & editing. Select the part of the gun you want to play around with.  At the bottom of the Dopesheet (to the right in your pic) you'll see a ghost icon. At the immediate left of that is an arrow icon.  Click on that, and only the selected object(s) will show in the Dopesheet and Graph editor.

Comment: Further to the above... When you also click on the ghost those selected items, if turned off in the Outliner with the EYE icon, will also appear.  The Action Editor is useful but I've rarely used it so I can't tell you much about that.  You can get into that, again from the bottom of the Dopesheet.  Expand the menu..

Comment: Take a look to the right of these comments. There are some good related questions/answers there.